# How to paginate an eager loaded association model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, eager-loading

I have the following code :

```
Post.where("user_id IN [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]").includes(:authors, :comments).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
```

what i want here is to eager load just `8 comments` per post using `will_paginate`, is this possible ? and how ?

Answer (score 0):

**Not a tested answer**

I don't see that possible from there, but:

```
Comment.joins(:posts).includes(:posts).where(posts: { user_id: [1,2,3,4,5,6] })
```

I am not sure if `joins` and `includes` can be called together.

This would give you a relation for comments you can continue working on, and you will have eager loaded posts:

```
@comments = Comment.joins(:post).includes(:post).where(posts: { user_id: [1,2,3,4,5,6] })
@comments.paginate(...)
```

If you want to get the posts from `@comments` I would do this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.post_ids
    all.map(&:post_id)
  end

  def self.posts
    Post.where(id: post_ids)
  end
end
```

Then use and paginate it:

```
@posts = @comments.posts.paginate(...)
```

Comment: the problem is that i use paginate in posts too